# How to fix Empathy startup bug and sudden crash?

Tags: 11.10, empathy, multimedia

In a fresh Ubuntu install from a bootable pendrive or a CD drive the empathy IM application crashes on startup. I faced problems in each installation and after a lot of trial & error methods I found out how to make empathy stable without any technical knowledge (no Terminal).

I just tried this:

*Start empathy from the menu somehow and quickly click on the “view” option and disable the offline contacts*

But this solves my problem until I reboot. After rebooting it resets itself.

While running from terminal it shows me 
*segmentation fault*

I tried this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/423316) also but not helpful yet.

sysinfo :

```
Release : Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric)
 GNOME  :  2.32.1 (Ubuntu 2011-04-14)
Kernel  : 3.0.0-13-generic (#22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 13:25:36 UTC 2011)
```

Comment: If there is no solution to this, you might try pidgin, it works.

Comment: @enedene : that is not solution to this question .

Comment: I said, "if there is no solution to this..."

Comment: Paradoxically, if you are getting a segmentation fault, that is a good thing. Turn on apport, reproduce the segmentation fault, and then it should offer to file a bug for you. You can then report back with the bug number here. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the permission command then started empathy from the terminal and disabled the view offline friends (It didn't crash after this) and restarted my computer. I started empathy and it is working perfectly.

just wanted to report on this as it seems like its not solved yet...

Answer (score 1):

> *After rebooting it resets itself*.

That could be an issue with file permissions. Maybe for some reason Empathy has not the rights to write in it's configuration files the settings that you made, because the permissions of the folders or files used by Empathy are wrong. Performing following command in terminal should fix this issue:

```
chmod -R 700 ~/.config/Empathy/ && chmod -R 700 .mission-control/accounts/
```

Comment: Empathy comes with ubuntu . so from my point there is no permission problem i tried above not working.